# Nativescript app doesn't show top bar in iOS emulator

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to run our Nativescript app in the iOS emulator so I can make screenshots of different sizes. However, the top bar that shows the title and the back button isn't shown in the emulator. If I click on it, the button does work, but it's not visible.

How can we get the top bar to be visible in the emulator?

See here the difference:

Screenshot from my iphone including top bar:
[image: Screenshot from my iphone including top bar]

Screenshot of emulator:
[image: Screenshot of emulator]

Comment: Hey so I'm gonna guess you're using iOS 15, right? This might be an issue with IOS: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420

Comment: Oh sorry didn't read the whole thing, but let me clarify. I ran into the same issue, but in my case it was due to using iOS 15. If your simulator is on a higher OS then it's possible that's the issue.

Comment: @FelipeCenteno My Simulator is run on iOS15. How do I run it on another version of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Updating nativescript to "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.0" resolved this issue :)